# Render list - React - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to render state

I see a few errors with declaring variables within the map loop.

Here is my attempt so far, Any help is welcomed

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const transformHumanReadableDateToMessages = date => {
  let d = new Date(date);
  const days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ];
  return {
    DayOfTheWeek: d.getDate(),
    Month: d.getMonth(),
    Day: days[d.getDay()],
    YearAtTime: d.getFullYear()
  };
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    messages: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/10xva4`).then(res => {
      let result = res.data["messages"];
          result = Array.from(new Set(result.map(e => JSON.stringify(e))));
          result.reduce((accu, curr) => {
           curr.date = transformHumanReadableDateToMessages(curr["sentAt"]);
            accu.push(curr)
            return accu;
          }, []);

      this.setState({
        messages: result
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
return (
  <>
    { this.state.messages.map(message => 
       let d = new Date(date);
      const days = [
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday"
      ];
     <div className="container">
     <p>{message.content}<p/>
     <p>{message.senderUuid}</p>
     <p>DayOfTheWeek: {d.getDate()}
     <p>Month: {d.getMonth()}</p>
     <p>Day: {days[d.getDay()]}</p>
     <p>Year: {d.getFullYear()} </p>
     </div>
     )}
  </>
);
```

}
    }

For example each element in the JSON that is returned looks like this:

```
{
  "sentAt":"2012-11-13T17:29:37.003Z",
  "uuid": "435453",
  "content": "1",
  "senderUuid": "2"
 }
```

I want to make the date more readable then add it to the element for a output like this:

```
{
 "sentAt":"2012-11-13T17:29:37.003Z",
 "uuid": "435453",
 "content": "1",
 "senderUuid": "2",
 "DayOfTheWeek": 22,
  "Month": 4,
  "Day": 'Friday',
  "YearAtTime": 2015
 }
```

Comment: Why, though? That information is directly derived from the `sentAt` and/or current date property, why not only generate the values you need for display purposes during  `render()`, which is the function that creates the actual bits users see? E.g.

Comment: I want to add more properties because later I want to had a button to sort the dates in either ascending or descending order using the `sentAt` value, instead of trying to rely on another function or handler when I render the sate @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: Okay, but... why would that matter? If you order by sentAt, the real code that's going to be in your `render()` will still yield the same derived values. Your sorting reorders the `messages` array (not in `render()`, in your handler for toggling sorting, using `setState`), and render then blindly regenerates the UI based on the updated `this.state.messages` array. That's how React works: you update the state in response to user actions, and `render()` renders your UI based on the updated state.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans okay I updated the question and code but still see errors

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @SILENT current errors is `Unexpected reserved word 'let'

Comment: sure, you forgot to use `{` and `}` around the multiline code you've put into `this.state.messages.map(message => ` - Are you not using syntax highlighting or code checking in your editor? That should have been a pretty obvious error in most modern code editors.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I wasn't using syntax highlighting

Comment: @bruce Please look at my answer. I rewrote your code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using let and jsx interchangeably due your mismanagement of brackets. Since it was a mess, I rewrote it using codesandbox and React hooks.

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-nobel-vlo34

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

const days = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday"
];
export default function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/10xva4`)
      .then(({ data: { messages } }) => setMessages(messages));
  }, []);
  const Display = messages.map(({ content, senderUuid, sentAt }, index) => {
    let d = new Date(sentAt);
    return (
      <div className="container" key={index}>
        <p>Content: {content}</p>
        <p>SenderUuid: {senderUuid}</p>
        <p>DayOfTheWeek: {d.getDate()}</p>
        <p>Month: {d.getMonth()}</p>
        <p>Day: {days[d.getDay()]}</p>
        <p>Year: {d.getFullYear()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
  // console.log({ messages });
  return <div className="App">{Display}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can say you would need to understand map function properly.
Also, how to handle logic inside JSX.

- First, You need to add return() function inside the map() function.
  As long as you don't return all your content inside the map()
  function, anything will not be rendered.

  - Second, You need to split variable assign outside of return function.
    So that return() inside map() function will only have JSX element.
    and other logic will be outside the return function body. Please take
    a look at the below code.
  - Third, You also need to fix your typo for

    tags in the map
    functions.

`<p>{message.content}<p/> <--- here typo : fix as </p>`

`<p>DayOfTheWeek</> doesn't have proper closing tag.`

- And last, You will need to handle if message is an empty array. so
  that, if the message state is an empty array, you should render
  something else.

The below example handles it.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

 export default class App extends React.Component {
   state = {
    messages: []
   };

  componentDidMount() {
    //... your api call here
  }

render() {
  const { messages } = this.state;

  if (messages.length === 0) {
    return <p>No Message Found</p>;
  }

  messages.map(message => {
    let d = new Date();
    const days = [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ];

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <p>{message.content}</p>
        <p>{message.senderUuid}</p>
        <p>DayOfTheWeek: {d.getDate()}</p>
        <p>Month: {d.getMonth()}</p>
        <p>Day: {days[d.getDay()]}</p>
        <p>Year: {d.getFullYear()} </p>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

}

Comment: the code doesn't appear to work  Current error `App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`